# Как вырезать или заменить расширение файла?

Tags: php

Нужно в конец названия скачиваемого файла (перед расширением) вставить текст, напр. (site.ru). Расширение всегда только mp3.

Так

**track(site.ru).mp3**

Кусок кода

```
class download {

var $properties = array ('old_name' => "", 'new_name' => "", 'type' => "", 'size' => "", 'resume' => "", 'max_speed' => "" );

var $range = 0;

function download($path, $name = "", $resume = 0, $max_speed = 0) {

    $name = ($name == "") ? substr( strrchr( "/" . $path, "/" ), 1 ) : $name;       

    $name = explode( "/", $name );
    $name = end( $name );


    $type = explode( ".", $name );
    $type = strtolower( end( $type ) );
```

Здесь

**$path** это название на сервере

**$name** это название которое прописывается файлу и которое нужно изменить. Оно сейчас такое **track.mp3**, а нужно так **track(site.ru).mp3**.

Пытался добавить после **$name = end( $name );**, чтобы просто удалить **.mp3**

```
$name = preg_replace("/.*?\./", '', $name);
```

но остаётся наоборот одно расширение.

Comment: `preg_replace("/(.*)\.mp3$/", "$1(site.ru).mp3", $fname)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего сделать через функцию [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php):

```
$name = end( $name );
$name = str_replace('.mp3', '(site.ru).mp3', $name);
```

Более надежный вариант:

```
$name = substr_replace($name, '(site.ru).mp3', -4);
```

Вариант не лучший, но самый простой.

Comment: Yeah: `str_replace('.mp3', '(site.ru).mp3', 'test.mp3.mp3'); // "test(site.ru).mp3(site.ru).mp3"`.

Comment: Я сказал что вариант не лучший, и не будет трека с названием test.mp3

Comment: Всё работает, а если не будет такого названия как test.mp3, в остальном всё в порядке будет?

Comment: Да, ещё можно более надежно сделать через substr_replace, ответ дополнил

Answer (score 1):

Без особых колдунств:

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/(\.mp3)$/', "(site.ru)$1", 'track.mp3')); // string(18) "track(site.ru).mp3"
```

http://regexr.com/3fgh1

Answer (score 0):

Если без регулярных выражений, то можно воспользоваться функцией strstr()

```
function filename($file, $url='(site.ru)') {
    $expansion = strstr($file, '.');
    $fileName = strstr($file, '.', true);

    return $fileName . $url . $expansion;
}

echo filename('track.mp3');//track(site.ru).mp3
```

Но на мой взгляд, лучше preg_replace(), предложенный выше.